# get first row per hour of actual day

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group

I got a table called 'pictures' with the following content:

```
picID   |   Date    |   Time    |   pic |   stationsID
1       22.02.2017  08:03:10    dadadjadadk 4
2       22.02.2017  08:13:10    ycycycycyc  4
3       22.02.2017  08:45:10    dagxhgdgwetk    4
4       22.02.2017  09:00:10    dadadjadadk 4
5       22.02.2017  09:03:10    asdasdasdyxcyw  4
6       22.02.2017  09:43:10    xvxvx       4
```

With the following query i got the result i want to - get only the first row per hour of the actual day:

```
select p.* from pictures p where p.Date = CURDATE() AND p.Time = (select min(p2.Time) from pictures p2 where p2.Date = p.Date and hour(p2.Time) = hour(p.Time) and p2.StationsID = 4);

1       22.02.2017  08:03:10    dadadjadadk 4
4       22.02.2017  09:00:10    dadadjadadk 4
```

But my sql query is very slow. Any idea how to optimize my query?

Comment: Tip: Store date and time as single entity. And an uncorrelated subquery is likely to be faster than a correlated one.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is reasonable:

```
select p.*
from pictures p
where p.Date = CURDATE() and
      p.StationsID = 4 and  -- added this condition because it seems needed
      p.Time = (select min(p2.Time)
                from pictures p2
                where p2.Date = p.Date and hour(p2.Time) = hour(p.Time) and
                      p2.StationsID = 4
               );
```

For this query, you want indexes.  I would recommend:  `pictures(Date, StationsId, Time)`.

Comment: a bit faster now :P

Comment: @Lukas . . . How much faster?

Comment: not that much faster, but i found a solution for my problem. See below

Answer (score 0):

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS pictures;

CREATE TABLE pictures
(picID   INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,dt DATETIME NOT NULL
,pic VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
,stationsID INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO pictures VALUES
(1,'2017-02-22 08:03:10'  ,  'dadadjadadk',4),
(2,'2017-02-22 08:13:10'  ,  'ycycycycyc',4),
(3,'2017-02-22 08:45:10'  ,  'dagxhgdgwetk',4),
(4,'2017-02-22 09:00:10'  ,  'dadadjadadk',4),
(5,'2017-02-22 09:03:10'  ,  'asdasdasdyxcyw',4),
(6,'2017-02-22 09:43:10'  ,  'xvxvx',4);


SELECT x.* 
  FROM pictures x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT MIN(dt) dt 
         FROM pictures 
        GROUP 
           BY DATE_FORMAT(dt,'%Y-%m-%d %h')
     ) y 
    ON y.dt = x.dt;
+-------+---------------------+-------------+------------+
| picID | dt                  | pic         | stationsID |
+-------+---------------------+-------------+------------+
|     1 | 2017-02-22 08:03:10 | dadadjadadk |          4 |
|     4 | 2017-02-22 09:00:10 | dadadjadadk |          4 |
+-------+---------------------+-------------+------------+
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, but changing the structure of my table would be the last option for me :/

Comment: @Lukas That's a pity.

Answer (score 0):

found a good solution:

```
    SELECT p.* FROM pictures p JOIN (
SELECT MIN(Time) as Time, MIN(picID) as picID FROM pictures 
WHERE StationsID = 4 AND 
Date = CURDATE() 
GROUP BY HOUR(Time)) p1 
ON p.picID = p1.picID;
```